# How does getBooleanExtra() work exactly?

Tags: android

I'm trying to understand some code from The Big Nerd Ranch Android Guide.  Here's the code:

```
public class CheatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.james.listview.geoquiz.answer_is_true";
private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;
private TextView mAnswerTextView;
private Button mShowAnswer;

public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);

    mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);

    mAnswerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_text_view);

    mShowAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button);
    mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mAnswerIsTrue) {
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.button_true);
            } else {
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.button_false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

I understand intents and passing through values.  Where I'm getting stuck is on the onClick for `mShowAnswer`.  The value received through `getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false)` can be either True or False depending on the situation.  My question is:

How does the condition for the if statement work?  Let's say `mAnswerIsTrue` = TRUE, then it makes sense to set `mAnswerTextView` to "TRUE".  But if `mAnswerIsTrue` = FALSE, it appears to me that `mAnswerTextView`--according to the code--should still set itself to "TRUE".  How does `mAnswerTextView` know to set itself to "FALSE"?

To be clear, the code works as intended.  I'm just unsure how it works.

Comment: Probably `onCreate` is not calling in second time are you calling `finish()` for Activity?

Comment: If mAnswer is true textView = "True", then if mAnswer is false textView = "False". Said that, where is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I try to comment your code so you can understand better :)

```
public class CheatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE = "com.james.listview.geoquiz.answer_is_true";
private boolean mAnswerIsTrue;
private TextView mAnswerTextView;
private Button mShowAnswer;

public static Intent newIntent(Context packageContext, boolean answerIsTrue) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(packageContext, CheatActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, answerIsTrue);
    return intent;
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cheat);
    //Here you get the boolean: you use the static key EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE and mAnswerIsTrue gain the bool value passed.
    mAnswerIsTrue = getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_ANSWER_IS_TRUE, false);

    //here you initialize the TextView so you can access it from the code
    mAnswerTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.answer_text_view);
    //and here you initialize the button for the same reason
    mShowAnswer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.answer_button);
    mShowAnswer.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //now, here is the problem: this is the contract form of if statement:
            //saying if(bool){dosomething}
            //is the same as saying if(bool == true){dosomething}

            //so this code is equals to:
            if(mAnswerIsTrue == true){
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.button_true);
            } else{
                //here you go if the bool is false
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.button_false);
            }


            if (mAnswerIsTrue) {//this means so if(bool == true)
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.button_true);
            } else { //and here you go if it is false
                mAnswerTextView.setText(R.string.button_false);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

i hope you got it, if you have questions tell me :)

Comment: I understand.  Thanks so much for your help!